# Filter spaces with setOnQuertTextListener

Tags: java, android-studio, android-arrayadapter

I am search ArrayAdapters for items which are inside of the array list, the issue I am having is when I am searching for data, the search feature works for the most part, it trips up when I use spaces, for example, '01' would work, but '01 April' would not work however.

I use the setOnQueryTextListener method and I am have a lot of trouble finding any solution to this.

Here is my code;

```
SearchView sv;

sv=(SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView1);

final ArrayAdapter Current = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, headlines);

setListAdapter(Current);

 sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
            Current.getFilter().filter(text);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Any help with this would be appreciated as I am having a lot of trouble getting the spaces to be filtered out and I'm unsure really how to go about it. Cheers.

Comment: why not just use the replace method on the string like this `text.replace(" ","");`

Comment: @SteelToe I tried implementing that but it doesn't work for one of my array lists as well as not working with certain combinations like '14 (' or '01 April', however full words will work e.g. 'Road users'

Comment: Can you explain a little clearer what is valid input and what is invalid input?

Comment: So the app is parsing data from an rss feed with title tags and description tags. The data from the rss is filling an arraylist and bound with an array adapter. Users should be able to search for a specific date which is inside of the description tags of the rss feed but when they search just now, it is only the title tags data which can be found with spaces and not the description tags, thanks to your replace technique.